# Create Knowledge Article in Flow

Tags: visual-workflow, knowledge

We're creating a Flow to allow certain users to create a Knowledge Article, based on the current record and a bunch of other related records.
I can collect all the data I need to create the Knowledge Article, but when it comes to actually creating the record I don't see that as an object I can create.

Is this even possible? Am I missing something?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.
I was missing Knowledge User permissions on my user.